# Count days on a column case

Tags: sql

I would like to create a SQL script that counts the number of age days and the  something like:(The catch is I got the days value of breaking value of one column by case to three columns) This is the output I have created.

```
Days0To30  Days30to60  Daysto60to90
----------------------------------
50$      | 10$        | 90$
60$      | 0          | 10$
0        | 0          | 5$
0        | 10$        | 0
10$      | 0          | 0
0$       | 0          | 0
1240     | 0          | 0
```

I would like to create a SQL script that counts the number of age days and the  something like:

```
------------------------------------------
Days0To30       | 4           
Days30to60      | 2           
Daysto60to90    | 3
```

Comment: what have you done so far (code)?

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using

Comment: Do you really want to match the expected result format, because both the answers below will have three columns with count respective count

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation`:

```
select count(case when Days0To30 <> 0 then 1 end) as Days0To30,
       count(case when Days30to60 <> 0 then 1 end) as Days30to60,
       count(case when Daysto60to90 <> 0 then 1 end) as Daysto60to90
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Days0To30 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Days0To30 ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Days30to60 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Days30to60,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Daysto60to90 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Daysto60to90
FROM   SOME_TABLE
```